# Modificar el archivo colors.xml de un proyecto android desde un xml externo

Tags: android, android-layout, xml

Tengo este `xml` en mi proyecto android `/res/values/colors.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#77ac5f</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#558a3d</color>
    <color name="colorFondo">#e9e9e9</color>
</resources>
```

Y tengo un xml en un servidor que se genera desde un `backoffice`  que tiene este formato:

```
<colores>   
    <color><hex>#ffffff</hex></color>
    <color><hex>#ffffff</hex></color>
    <color><hex>#ffffff</hex></color>
</colores>
```

Lo que quiero es que si la app tiene conexión a internet, obtenga los datos del `xml` y modifique el archivo `colors.xml`. ¿Es posible realizar lo que digo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Modificar el archivo colors.xml de un proyecto android desde un xml
>   externo

**Los xml de los recursos no pueden ser modificados, ya que son de solo lectura.** No puedes modificar estos recursos, lo que te sugiero es tomar los colores del archivo que sugieres y no hacer referencia a los que se encuentran en `colors.xml`

Comment: Aunque reciba -1 definitivamente **no se pueden sobreescribir los archivos de recursos del proyecto**.